# Webupd8 Oracle Java8 on rpi missing javaws.policy

Tags: apt, java, raspberrypi

I'm trying to install Oracle java8 on my raspberry pi 3.

My script follows the instructions at http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html. I tried both the option of downloading the tar and allowing the installer to download it automatically. Both result in the same error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libopts25 python3-urllib3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core
  ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho
  | ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming firefox | firefox-2 | iceweasel
  | mozilla-firefox | iceape-browser | mozilla-browser | epiphany-gecko
  | epiphany-webkit | epiphany-browser | galeon | midbrowser
  | moblin-web-browser | xulrunner | xulrunner-1.9 | konqueror
  | chromium-browser | midori | google-chrome
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  oracle-java8-installer
Preconfiguring packages ...
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/23.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 93.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 31968 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java8-installer_8u101+8u101arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
oracle-license-v1-1 license has already been accepted
Unpacking oracle-java8-installer (8u101+8u101arm-1~webupd8~0) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2) ...
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u101+8u101arm-1~webupd8~0) ...
Installing from local file /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u101-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz
Removing outdated cached downloads...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/appletviewer to provide /usr/bin/appletviewer (appletviewer) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/extcheck to provide /usr/bin/extcheck (extcheck) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/idlj to provide /usr/bin/idlj (idlj) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jar to provide /usr/bin/jar (jar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jarsigner to provide /usr/bin/jarsigner (jarsigner) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javadoc to provide /usr/bin/javadoc (javadoc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javah to provide /usr/bin/javah (javah) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javap to provide /usr/bin/javap (javap) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jcmd to provide /usr/bin/jcmd (jcmd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jconsole to provide /usr/bin/jconsole (jconsole) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jdb to provide /usr/bin/jdb (jdb) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jdeps to provide /usr/bin/jdeps (jdeps) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jhat to provide /usr/bin/jhat (jhat) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jinfo to provide /usr/bin/jinfo (jinfo) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jmap to provide /usr/bin/jmap (jmap) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jps to provide /usr/bin/jps (jps) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jrunscript to provide /usr/bin/jrunscript (jrunscript) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jsadebugd to provide /usr/bin/jsadebugd (jsadebugd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jstack to provide /usr/bin/jstack (jstack) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jstat to provide /usr/bin/jstat (jstat) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jstatd to provide /usr/bin/jstatd (jstatd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/native2ascii to provide /usr/bin/native2ascii (native2ascii) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/rmic to provide /usr/bin/rmic (rmic) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/schemagen to provide /usr/bin/schemagen (schemagen) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/serialver to provide /usr/bin/serialver (serialver) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/wsgen to provide /usr/bin/wsgen (wsgen) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/wsimport to provide /usr/bin/wsimport (wsimport) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/xjc to provide /usr/bin/xjc (xjc) in auto mode
mv: cannot stat '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/javaws.policy': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
```

Note the line below, which I think is the cause of the error.

```
mv: cannot stat '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/javaws.policy': No such file or directory
```

I've googled *extensively* and can't find any mention of this anywhere on the interwebs.

Strangely, I've provisioned dozens of Pis with this script already some months ago and - although it was also a ball-ache back then for other reasons - I didn't have this problem.

Anyone got any ideas? Or can point me to a forum/irc channel where people who might have an idea can be found?

Cheers, much appreciated

Comment: I got in touch with the wepupd8 people and it appears that there was an issue with a recent change. So... if you're getting this issue too, then you've probably got to wait for their fix to roll out, same as me :/ Should be any moment now though :D

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this file must be left out of the installation.  Perhaps you could wait for them to fix the distribution.  I wrote a little script that watched for the creation of the target directory, then dropped a javaws.policy file into it.

```
while [ ! -d "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/" ]
  do
  sleep 1
  done
cp javaws.policy /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/
```

I started this script before the install/update in a one window, then did the install/update in another window.

Here's the contents of the javaws.policy I created:

```
grant codeBase "file:${jnlpx.home}/javaws.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I'm not really too concerned with the contents since I doubt I'll be using Java WebStart on this platform.